# prime ideal is a discrete valuation ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to show the following:

Let $R$ be a subring of an integer ring $\mathcal{O}_K$, and suppose that as groups, $R$ is an index $m$ subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_k$. Prove that if $P \subset R$ is a prime ideal that does not contain $m$, then $R_P$, the local ring at $P$, is a discrete valuation ring (DVR).

This is a homework problem, but I'm quite stumped so I'm hoping for a small push in the right direction. Thanks!

What I have so far is that the value $m$ must be a unit of $R_P$. Also, the only method I'm aware of for showing something is a DVR is to find a uniformiser (an element that generates the maximal ideal), but I'm not having any luck on this front.

Comment: I'm confused, but this is NEVER correct unless $R=\mathcal{O}_K$. Indeed, by assumption $\mathrm{Frac}(R)=K$. So, now if $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is integrally closed or all $\mathfrak{p}$, then $R$ is integrally closed. But, you just said that $R\to\mathcal{O}_K$ is an integral extension, and so we conclude conclude that $R=\mathcal{O}_K$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm not sure if $Frac(R) = K$ is an assumption. The fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is certainly $K$, but I don't believe that is necessarily true for a subring of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Perhaps there's a misunderstanding about the term 'index' as well? By this I mean that taking $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $R$ as groups, $R$ is an index $m$ subgroup. I'll make an edit.

Comment: But, it is true of one for finite index. If $[\mathcal{O}_K:R]=m$, then for all $x\in\mathcal{O}_K$, you have that $mx\subseteq R$. So, $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq \frac{1}{m}R$. This then implies they have the same fraction field.

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that, but you're definitely correct. I'll have to think about whether or not we can conclude that $R= \mathcal{O}_K$ though, I don't think that we'd be assigned a problem that wasn't true. Thank you very much for helping though!

Comment: I think I accidentally left out part of the question. $P$ must not contain $m$, so $R_p$ would only be integrally closed on these $P$, but not all $P$.

Comment: OK. You should ping me with "AlexYoucis", else I don't know you've responded. :) In that case, use our discussion above about containments to show that if $m\notin P$, then $R_P=(\mathcal{O}_K)_P$. PS, if you like geometric intuition, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is like a smooth curve, and $R$ is like a curve birational to $\mathcal{O}_K$ but with some singular points (essentially the points which contain $m$, for $m$ chosen correctly).

Comment: Ah great, thank you very much! If you want repost your comment as an answer to the question, I can up vote your answer and mark this question as answered! @AlexYoucis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the hint as provided above. Since $[\mathcal{O}_K:R]=m$, then

$$\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq \frac{1}{m}R$$

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $R$ not containing $m$, then use the above to show that $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is the localization of a $\mathcal{O}_K$ at a prime.